# TypeOrmModule in Nest causes controller params to be undefined

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

In my Nest js app, This is the code of the app.controller:

```
@Controller('app')
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('/:id')
  getHello(@Param('id') id: string): string {
    console.log(id);
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

It works perfect using the request:
localhost:3000/app/1

When I add a functionality in my app.module to work with Postgres:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    CacheModule.register({ isGlobal: true }),
    HttpModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: ['.env.dev'],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The application is running, but I see that when I call to:
localhost:3000/app/1
it gets to my controller with "undefined" in the param.

I will appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeorm updated their version of `reflect-metadata` to `0.2.1` recently. Nest is compatible with it, but you need to update your application's version of it to match. Simply run your package manager's `install` command with the target as `reflect-metadata@^0.2` and everything should be fine.

```bash
npm install reflect-metadata@^0.2
pnpm install reflect-metadata@^0.2
yarn add reflect-metadata@^0.2
```

Comment: Man I appreciate your answer so much, it has solved my problem. Thanks !